# how to change the name of calculated field in pivot table using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have used below code. But still its not updating the name of calculated field.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotName).CalculatedFields.Add "basic_amt", _
    "=((amount + other_charges) - discount_amt)", True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("basic_amt").Orientation = xlDataField
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("basic_amt").Name = "Basic Amount"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("basic_amt").NumberFormat = "###0.00"
```

Comment: If my answer helped you please let me know :) And mark it as accepted!

Comment: Sorry Teasel but it did not help me..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can update **all pivot tables** using the following code:

```
'Refresh All Pivot Tables
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

To update a **specific pivot table** within the sheet:

```
'Refresh A Single Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("YourPivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh
```

If you want to update a **specific pivot table** in **another sheet** you can use:

```
'Refresh A Single Pivot Table
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").PivotTables("YourPivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh
```